# IP Cam stream loads too slow

Tags: android, xamarin, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have a `VideoView` which gets a URI from an Ip Cam. My problem is that the stream take between 20-25 seconds to load and start showing what's happening.

`rtsp://user:pass0@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/Streaming/Channels/xxx`

I think that is caused by the `RTSP` protocol. ¿Some alternatives or solutions?

Here my code:

```
public void StartStream(VideoView vView, String uri){ //rtsp://user:pass0@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/Streaming/Channels/xxx

    vView.SetVideoUri(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uri));
    vView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    vView.Prepared += delegate
    {
         vView.Start();
    };


}
```

The IP cameras are from HikVision.

Any way to get faster stream load?

Comment: Not that it answers your issue, but have you tried other video players, such as ExoPlayer?

Comment: I try loading the stream in VLC too and it takes 15 seconds to load ...

Comment: Please try to review this guid: https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-troubleshoot-rtsp-rtp-playback